# jQuery: how to I append $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, append

I have a jQuery method that I want to append the element $(this) to.

My code is

```
$("#actions ul" ).append($(this));
```

However this does seem to do anything. Using the line

```
.append($(this).html())
```

does work, but it only grabs the child of $(this) (a div) not the whole element (an li).

I'm probably doing something moronic, hopefully someone can point this out to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! We need to see more code.  Where is $(this) coming from? a click event, a mouse over? Where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what `this` refers to, the only reason I can think of for `$(this).html()` to work and not `$(this)` is that the former method creates a new element from the html code whereas appending `$(this)` will move the element.

See if the below fixes your problem:

```
$("#actions ul" ).append($(this).clone());
```

Comment: Thanks yep it was the .clone() function that I was missing

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear what `$(this)` refers to, but if it's the child element of the element you want then `$(this).parent()` should get the parent element you're after.

Comment: append() accepts string, element or jQuery object, so .append($(this).parent()) is enough. Plus, appending a jQuery object will move the element, rather than cloning it in the case of $(this).parent().html().

Comment: @box9 - Thanks for the correction, I didn't realise that about append(). I've removed that part from my answer then to keep it accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `this` is set to a selector that finds the `<div>` instead of the `<li>`.  You can either change the selector or, like miket2e suggests, use `.parent()` instead.  Note: you should not have to use `.html()` as well since [the `.append` function](http://api.jquery.com/append/) can take a HTML string **or** a jQuery object.

If you post the value of `this`, we could provide a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to use appendTo, this will grab the entire element.

```
$(this).appendTo("#actions ul");
```